# View SVG using Silverlight or Flash

Tags: flash, silverlight, svg

Is there a way to view a SVG from either a file or webpage dynamically using Silver light or flash?

**Edit:**  I am currently converting them on the server using inkscape.  The only trouble with this is the time it takes to make all 60+ pages of the catalog is a little slow.  It take 5 min to make it, and some customers (boss included) would like this process to be quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally Inkscape has support for exporting SVG images to XAML output.  Neither of course is exactly what you are asking for as both "convert" in some manner, but to directly answer -- No, Silverlight does not interpret SVG directly.  I'm not sure about Flash though.

Comment: I will look into this to see the time it takes.

Answer (score 1):

[XamlTune](http://www.codeplex.com/XamlTune) can convert SVG to XAML for viewing in a Silverlight control.

Answer (score 0):

**timheuer:**  Do you know if there is a command line option to make the XAML file?

**EDIT:** it seems that svg does not directly translate to the xaml format, as my diagrams will crash IE in XP and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

milhous: I'm not familiar with Inkscape's command-line interface (if any), but you can take an SVG and save as Microsoft XAML.

Answer (score 0):

The [SVG project at codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/svg/) can read and render an SVG file to a Graphics object which you might be able to use in Silverlight. Alternatively you can just use the HttpHandler to render the SVG straight to the browser in PNG format.